# IIS / ASP.Net: session info lost using StateServer with 32-bit application in web garden

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-10

I am finding that when I turn on the "Enable 32-bit applications" parameter in an application pool, while also using an out-of-process state server, the session state is not maintained across worker processes (as though IIS is ignoring my state server configuration and using inProc). There are specific reasons for this application why I need both 32-bit enabled and multiple worker processes (there is a Crystal Reports library which I must call which operates in 32-bit, and that same library has some nasty process blocking which will halt access to the rest of the site if there aren't multiple worker processes).

I verified the basics (multiple browsers: Firefox, Chrome, IE, Edge, and Safari), triple-checked the state server config (running, tcp port correct, machine keys configured in IIS,  TCPIP loopback:42424 as the target, etc). I made a dummy 1-page project just to save a GUID under the session state whenever no previous GUID is known, and then did an ajax refresh showing the GUID and worker process ID and I can see that each process ID returns different a different GUID (GUID follows process ID). It really seems like IIS ignores the out-of-process state server as soon as the 32-bit applications switch is flipped. Any information appreciated on how to fix this problem.

Edited to add: I just put my little test site on a 2012 R2 server and the problem did not occur. It seems to be a problem in IIS 10 / Server 2016.

Comment: I haven't got an answer, but it might be useful to add the version of IIS to the question. Also, have you tried using SQL Server as the state server, just to test?

Comment: I just added the IIS info. It does seem to pertain to IIS 10 specifically, as I could not replicate on IIS 8.

Comment: You could check if it is even using the state server by creating some activity which should use it and monitor the activity of the ASP.NET State Service (aspnet_state). I think that the minimum memory usage is 4KB per state stored.